# Criar filtro de 90 dias anterior a um período

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Preciso que traga os resultados que completaram 90 dias dentro de um período informado.

Por exemplo, tenho a posssibilidade de fazer:

`DT_INICIO_REAL <= (sysdate-90)`, vou ter como resultado 90 dias da data atual

ou `DT_INICIO_REAL BETWEEN :DT_INICIO AND :DT_FIM` 
vou ter resultados do período informado.

Mas preciso "mesclar" as duas coisas, quero que informe um período, por exemplo 01/10/2017 até 10/10/2017 e me traga as linhas em que `DT_INICIO_REAL` completa 90 dias dentro do período informado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que tal:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABELA
WHERE
    DT_INICIO_REAL BETWEEN to_date('01-OCT-2017') and to_date('10-OCT-2017') AND
    (trunc(sysdate) - DT_INICIO_REAL) >= 90;
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d6c24e/2)

Comment: Você me fez ir atrás dessa função `trunc`. Achei [um uso aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/108836/64969) e, nele, a documentação: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm

Comment: `sysdate` retorna o dia e a hora local. A função `trunc()` serve para converter um tipo `TIMESTAMP` para `DATE`, "truncando" as horas, os minutos  e os segundos.